# sending list of product to email

Tags: php, mysql, email

im trying to send a list of products user ordered from my website..im able to send the email but the product list is just showing array..any help will be appreciated. thanks :)

here is my sql for fetching the product list:

```
$data = array();
$sql = mysql_query("select oi.id ,oi.quantity, p.code, p.name from order_items oi left join product p on p.id = oi.product_id where order_id = $orderID ");
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $code = ($result['code'] != "") ? $result['code'] : $result['name'];
 $quantity = $result['quantity'];
 $data[] = ''.$code.' - '.$quantity.'';
 //$content2 = implode("<br>", $data); 
 }
```

the email part:

```
   $mail_content .= '<table id="mytable" cellspacing="0" style="">';
   $mail_content .= '<tr >';
   $mail_content .= '<td width="20%">product</td>';
   $mail_content .= '<td width="20%">Unit Type</td>';
   $mail_content .= '<td width="10%">Quantity</td>';
   $mail_content .= '</tr>';

   $mail_content .= '<tr>';
   $mail_content .= "<td>";
   $mail_content .= "$data";
   $mail_content .= "</td>";
   $mail_content .= '<td width="20%">Unit Type</td>';
   $mail_content .= '<td width="10%">Quantity</td>';
   $mail_content .= '</tr>';
   $mail_content .= '</table>';
```

Comment: because $data is an array you want to loop through it (`foreach()` is a good option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what the values for "product" and "Unit Type" are from the db

change:

```
$data[] = ''.$code.' - '.$quantity.'';
```

to

```
$data[] = array('code'=>$code,'quantity'=>$quantity)
```

then

```
$mail_content .= '<table id="mytable" cellspacing="0" style="">';
$mail_content .= '<tr >';
$mail_content .= '<td width="20%">product</td>';
$mail_content .= '<td width="20%">Unit Type</td>';
$mail_content .= '<td width="10%">Quantity</td>';
$mail_content .= '</tr>';

foreach($data as $d){
$mail_content .='<tr><td>'.$d['code'].'</td><td>unit type ?</td><td>'.$d['quantity'].'</td></tr>';
}


$mail_content .= '</table>';
```

Comment: product is the name of product..and i have tried ur code but nothing showed

Comment: hmm wht u mean by populated?